# su - Authentication failure; account accessible from root, not from user

Tags: password, root, oracle, su

I know there are tons of articles about authentication failure, but I think my case is specific.
I have created groups and user `oracle` using this link:
http://en.kioskea.net/faq/4405-linux-installing-oracle-11g-on-ubuntu#update-the-configuration-of-system-users

I can access the user from root, but not from my account.
What is wrong in setup of `oracle` user?

Steps:

#### Add groups: oinstall, dba, nobody

```
# addgroup oinstall        
    Adding group 'oinstall' (GID 1001) ...        
 Done.        
# addgroup dba        
 Adding group 'dba' (GID 1002) ...        
 Done.        
# addgroup nobody        
    Adding group 'nobody' (GID 1003) ...        
    Done.        
# usermod -g nobody nobody
```

#### Add oracle user

```
# useradd -g oinstall -G dba -p password -d /home/oracle -s /bin/bash oracle        
# passwd oracle        
    Password changed.        
# mkdir /home/oracle        
# chown -R oracle:dba /home/oracle
```

Verification:

```
[jakub@petol:~/programy/oracle]
$ sudo su
[sudo] password for jakub: 
root@petol:/home/jakub/programy/oracle# 
root@petol:/home/jakub/programy/oracle# su - oracle
oracle@petol:~$ passwd
Zmienianie hasła dla oracle.    (password change for user oracle)
(obecne) hasło UNIX: 
Proszę podać nowe hasło UNIX: 
Proszę ponownie podać hasło UNIX: 
passwd: hasło zostało zmienione    (password changed)
oracle@petol:~$ groups
oinstall dba
oracle@petol:~$ id
uid=1001(oracle) gid=1001(oinstall) grupy=1001(oinstall),1002(dba)
oracle@petol:~$ exit
logout
root@petol:/home/jakub/programy/oracle# exit
exit
[jakub@petol:~/programy/oracle]
$ su - oracle
Hasło: 
su: Uwierzytelnienie nie powiodło się  (authentication failure)
[jakub@petol:~/programy/oracle]
$ sudo -i
root@petol:~# exit
logout
[jakub@petol:~/programy/oracle]
$
```

Edit:

```
$ sudo passwd -S oracle
oracle P 11/01/2014 0 99999 7 -1
```

Comment: Is the account locked? Try `sudo passwd -u oracle` and then try `su - oracle`.

Comment: first command issued successfully, but still cannot authenticate